Angular 11 - Typescript 4.1.6 - Property or signature expected
I recently migrated my Angular application from 10 to 11. The migration was successful. And as I was using Node 18 which did not provide support for Angular 11, I had make some adjustments and executed npm start command.
After executing the command I started to get error -
Error: ../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1426:5 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

get selector(): string;

../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1426:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get selector(): string;
         ~~~~~~~~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1426:19 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get selector(): string;
                   ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1430:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get type(): Type<C>;
         ~~~~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1430:15 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get type(): Type<C>;
               ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1430:24 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

get type(): Type<C>;
                        ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1434:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get inputs(): ReadonlyArray<{
         ~~~~~~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1434:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get inputs(): ReadonlyArray<{
                 ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1437:7 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

}>;
       ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1441:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get outputs(): ReadonlyArray<{
         ~~~~~~~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1441:18 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get outputs(): ReadonlyArray<{
                  ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1444:7 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

}>;
       ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1448:9 - 91merror TS1005: ';' expected.

get ngContentSelectors(): ReadonlyArray<string>;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1448:29 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get ngContentSelectors(): ReadonlyArray<string>;
                             ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1448:52 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

get ngContentSelectors(): ReadonlyArray<string>;
                                                    ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1453:9 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get isStandalone(): boolean;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1453:23 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

get isStandalone(): boolean;
                       ~
../workspace-bi/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:1454:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

}

I don't understand what went wrong here as the errors are regarding angular/core. Given is the version -
"@angular/core": "11.2.14"

Did you used ng update? It should perform additional updates (typescript, ...)

While migrating, first I did ng update, then I updated all the packages mentioned after executing the command and that was successful. Later I again remove node_modules and rerun npm i --legacy-peer-deps. Then I did npm start

Usually this kind or errors are related to typescript version/misconfiguration, or node version. Check your node is compatible with angular 11. Also add the content of "start" command to your question (it's in package.json).

My bad. I found the issue. One of the component created by my fellow colleague was importing dependencies from another project. I had migrated my current project but as the another project was still using old Angular version, I was getting this error. Fixed the issue with proper imports.
